# How to web scrape innerHTML that has "&nbsp;" instead of the actual value you see in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to web scrape a table in HTML using Cheerio- below is the particular HTML in question:

```
<tr>
   <td class="n3">
       Course / Speed
   </td>
   <td class="v3" id="spv0">145.5° / 0.0 kn</td>
</tr>
```

However, I noticed that instead of getting "145.5° / 0.0 kn", I instead get "**&nbsp**". Indeed, when I click on view page source, the td element has the empty space string instead of the actual numerical value I am looking for.  Why is that happening, and how can I get Cheerio in NodeJS to fetch "**145.5° / 0.0 kn**" instead?

Comment: looks like there is a script running that sets the content at runtime... but that's not in your snippet...

Comment: if that content is generated by JS, I don't think Cheerio will work. You would have to use a real browser "simulator" like Puppeteer, for example, to run the code and then read the results

Comment: How would I know if there's a script that's running in the background that lazily sets the actual value?

Comment: Open the page in chrome with network tab open and then search for the value. That will tell you which response it was in.